# Common library files for all project

Tags: svn, ant, jenkins

I am using jenkins as CI tool and using ant for build with sources in svn repository. Each and every project in jenkins has its own libraries. This takes the space of jenkins at the time of build process. Is there a way to have a lib folder common to all with jenkins or ant build.

Comment: You could consider using a Maven repository to store common binaries. Client tools like the Maven ANT task and Apache ivy can then be used to document what each project depends on. Advanced topic but worth looking into

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  I frequently ran into this problem with large projects.

In order to have a single repo location for all tools and shared libraries, add all tools & libraries to a single repo and add that to a single job.

Then we scheduled the tools repo to run nightly to make sure the tools were updated.  The Node Label Plugin allows you to run a job on all nodes simultaneously.  That updates all ndoes with the tools repo.

Then you references the tools repo in you main jobs.  The Tools repo workspace will be up one relative path from the other jobs:

"%WORKSPACE%....\ToolsRepo\workspace\"

Or you can add the Tools in the tools repo to your jenkins env variables which get exported to each build node.  I prefer the former, since adding variables to the jenkins master assumes that all build nodes have the same setup, same OS, etc, which isn't always the case.

Edit: adding the following:
you can have ant perform a svn checkout of the libraries project into the current working directory under a sub dir (such as .\lib). Or you can download the latest build artifact from your library job's workspace. So if "Job1" is the job that stores the approved version of each of your libraries and Job2 is the current job, then you can directly refer to the latest build artifacts (stored on your jenkins server) from inside of your Job2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to call lib files through ant from remote server

Comment: Yes, you can have ant perform a svn checkout of the libraries project into the current working directory under a sub dir (such as .\lib).

Or you can download the latest build artifact from your library job's workspace. So if "Job1" is the job that stores the approved version of each of your libraries and Job2 is the current job, then you can directly refer to the latest build artifacts (stored on your jenkins server) from inside of your Job2.